# Checking if window size has changes and performance/optimalization

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance, optimization, plugins

today I'm implementing slider plugin and I have one question about it:

I want to make it responsive, but to achive that (depending on my current implementation) I should add another function which will detect if browser window size has changed - and here's my question - is it good for overall performance? Or maybe I should re-think about my solution and try to build it with pure css?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/about

Answer (score 0):

The browser resize is only temporary and personally I don't see the big hassle for a slight hiccup in that phase.

Since you refer to jquery, you can just add

```
$(window).resize(function() { ... });
```

Add it withing the document ready, and you will do good to call it one on load. Just do

```
$(window).resize();
```

As far as performance, you are correct that every little addon will have effect on the performance, but only when it is active. When the window is not resized, teh event does not get fired.

Answer (score 0):

`<div id="resized"></div>`

```
function display() {
    var p = document.createElement("p");

    p.textContent = "resize event";
    document.getElementById("resized").appendChild(p);
}

$(window).on("resize", display);
```

or using javascript

```
function display() {
    var p = document.createElement("p");

    p.textContent = "resize event";
    document.getElementById("resized").appendChild(p);
}

window.addEventListener("resize", display, false);
```

on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Xotic750/Q8zN6/)